# Why node js middleware using Express after successful authorization does not call given API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have below setup to call API with middleware to authorize it before success.

1. Calling API with **token i**d with **header** object using jquery ajax,

> ```
>     $.ajax({
>
>     url : '/api/auth/fetchMycontent',
>     type: 'POST',
>     dataType: 'json',
>     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>     cache: false,
>     context: this,
>
>     headers: {
>         "X-Access-Token": tokenId
>     },
>     data: JSON.stringify({
>         accountId: accountId
>     }),
>     success: function(data){
>         //render data in HTML
>
>     }
>
> });
> ```

2. Setting node server as below,

> ```
> var express = require('express'); 
> var app = express(); 
> var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
> // Add your middlewares:
> var middleware = require("middlewares");
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> app.all('/api/auth/*', middleware.apiValidate);
> app.use('/', require('./modelApi'));
> ...
> ```

3. setting API in modelApi/index.js,

> ```
>   var express = require('express'),
>   router = express.Router(),
>   api = require('../api.js'),
>   router.post('/api/auth/fetchMycontent', api.fetchMycontent);
>   module.exports = router;
> ```

4. middleware.js file will be like

> ```
>   module.exports = {
>   apiValidate: function (req, res, next) {
>
>     var token = req.body.x_access_token;
>     if (token) {
>       elastic.fetchToken(table, token).then(function (data) {
>        
>         if (data.hits.total > 0) {
>           **//authorization success but next() fails here <------**
>           next();
>         } else {
>           res.json({
>             message: "Invalid User access!!",
>           });
>           return;
>         }
>       });
>     }
>   },
> };
> ```

5. From api.js,fetchMycontent function will be like

> ```
>     fetchMycontent : function(req, res) {
>     **console.log('not reaching after authorization success !!!')**
>     elastic.fectMycontent(table, req.body).then(function (data) {              
>                     res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
>                             res.status(200);
>                             res.send(data);
>                 })
>     }
> ```

When i call api '**fetchMycontent**', it calls middleware as expected and authorize it and does not call fetchMycontent()!!! What am i missing here? Please advise

Thanks in advance

Comment: In step 3, are you exporting the `router`? Probably you missed to include here, but just confirming. What is the response if any, you are getting for that call now?

Comment: MatJ, I use express router in step 3,var express = require('express'),router = express.Router(),....

Comment: MatJ, after Middleware call, it doesn't reach actual fetch content call...

Comment: No, I mean, at the end of `modelApi/index.js` file, do you have a `module.exports=router` line that you missed to include here?

Comment: Mat J, module.exports = router; had added but was missed here. now it is added. My response would be json if it is successfully calling

Comment: Mat J, I found the issue. I used to concatinate base url with // which gives issue. now removed one / and working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to extend like 
`export class AuthenticationMiddleware implements ExpressMiddlewareInterface`
and implement the `use` function 
`use(req, res, next)`

Comment: Please check my updated code with formatter. And check middleware.js

Answer (score 0):

Base url was added with two slash,  Fixed by removing one / and it is working fine.